# Properties to allow shadowbox to work

Tags: javascript, html, css, shadowbox

My question is a little unconventional. I want to use shadowbox to display a HTML page. I have created a test hyperlink and it works perfectly on it. Now, I am using a css template, and I am abke to geerate a similar code required for shadowbox to work. However, it does not work. Can someone please tell me what properties of the  tag or any other of the parent DOM should I look into to make it work.

## Adding some code

If I use this

```
<a href="playVideo?vid=oysur61F3uY&service=youtube" rel="shadowbox">
<img class="media" src="http://s1.dmcdn.net/D0-dx/x120-jai.jpg">
<a>
```

as a simple link, it opens the page in shadowbox

However when the same code is generated through javascipt, the link doesnt open in shadowbox. I have checked the outer divs, nothing seems to influence this. What things do I need to check?

Comment: We're going to need to see some code if we are to help. [jsfiddles](http://www.jsfiddle.net) are greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: It is a little difficult to post everything online. But basically I am using a code similar to this http://www.satine.org/research/webkit/snowleopard/snowstack.html . (Actually I am using https://code.google.com/p/css-vfx/source/browse/trunk/snowstack/snowstack-video.html?r=73 ) I just want to open the links in a shadowbox (http://www.shadowbox-js.com/download.html)